# QGIS Bézier-editing plugin does not honor id-creating rule when saving new line feature

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, rule-based

I have started using the QGIS Bézier Editing Plugin by Takayuki Mizutani v.1.3.4. Plotting line features in my project works well, but on saving the feature the attributes dialog is empty, whereas when I save a feature via the standard procedure, the attribute rules provide a new id-number from the database. Which pyqgis function applies the attribute rules to a new feature ? My QGIS version is 3.4.11-Madeira.

** Partial answer **

Playing with the excellent and necessary plugin IPython to inspect the data model, I found this Python expression:
`testlayer.fields().field(0).defaultValueDefinition.expression()`
which evaluates to
`'if(count(@layer_id)=0,1,maximum("id")+1)'`
which is the default id number expression I am looking for. Then I grepped the codebase to search for "expression" and found the class `QgsExpression`. It can be instantiated with the string representation of the above expression, which is automatically parsed on init. You can query the `hasParserErrors` property or the `isValid` property to check all is right.

But then you are on your own again. The expression class has a method `evaluate` which should return the new id value, but it needs a `QgsExpressionContext` to provide the expression with the attributes of the `testlayer` features to calculate its result. The constructor of the expression context class only has a `QgsExpressionContextScope` stack as arguments. There also exists a `QgsExpressionContextGenerator` abstract interface, which should be implemented by the user.

So my question is narrowed down to how does the standard new feature dialog for `LineString` features with among others an `id` attribute create this expression context ?

Comment: Have you created any attributes on the layer? If you have no attributes, it would be no wonder the dialog is empty. You should add more information and add a screenshot so that we know what you have. Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

Basis: see the ** Partial Answer ** section in my edited question.

After more studying of the C++ source I found this class: `QgsVectorLayerUtils`. It has a method `createFeature` which honors all constraints the user has set on the vector layer in question. You just give it the vector layer as argument, and you receive a blank new feature on which all defaults are set.

You then copy the geometry from the feature the plugin has constructed and set the new feature in the feature attributes dialog of the plugin, so you can add the new attributes for the feature. The feature attributes dialog is provided by the vector layer, and applies the constraints.